# Cannot install transformers in docker

Tags: docker

I'm trying to pass "RUN pip install transformers==3.4.0" to my docker file on ubuntu image, but I get

Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

Error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.

With "RUN pip install transformers" the build goes through fine. Also, I tried to install from inside the container, but no luck there.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers

I tried "RUN pip install transformers". Build goes fine, but I need 3.4.0.